# Text from TextBox to Widget?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

So i am making an iOS app, that lets you to enter text into a TextBox and then there is a Button that will display the "Text" on a label, and that "Text" on the label will be Displayed in the Notification Center, on a widget, But something is going wrong Because every time i run the app it fails and throws me into the `AppDelegate.Swift` and highlights me this specific part: "`class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {`"

with an error that says "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

i Don't know what else to do ;( please help!!

This is the ViewController.Swift code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var UserInput: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var TextDisplay: UILabel!

    @IBAction func DisplayButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        let Text:String = UserInput.text!

        if  let Text = Int(Text) {

            print("Computer says no!")

        } else {
            TextDisplay.text = (Text)

        }



    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        let SharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.St33v3n.TextOnWidget")

        SharedDefaults?.setObject(UserInput, forKey: "StringKey")

        SharedDefaults?.synchronize()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

and Here is the TodayView controller code (the one from the widget):

```
import UIKit

import NotificationCenter

class TodayViewController: UIViewController, NCWidgetProviding {


    @IBOutlet var TextToWidget: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: ((NCUpdateResult) -> Void)) {


        let ShareDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName:"group.St33v3n.TextOnWidget")

        self.TextToWidget.text = ShareDefaults?.objectForKey("StringKey") as? String

        completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.NewData)
    }

}
```

Comment: What is printed on console? Maybe sth like this: `unexpectadly found nil while unwrapping an optional value`?

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
SharedDefaults?.setObject(UserInput, forKey: "StringKey")
```

you are passing UITextField object, not the text. You should use

```
SharedDefaults?.setObject(UserInput.text, forKey: "StringKey")
```

I'm not sure if that is causing the crash, but it needs correction anyway ;)

Comment: Thanks David! yes, it seems that stopped the crash, now there is a problem, that on the widget it is not showing the text, it only keeps showing the text by default that is "Hello world" any idea?

Comment: Sure ;) You have to somehow invoke widget update, because widgets are not updated regullary. You can use [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole) for example or you have to periodically update the widget using NSTimer or dispatch_after().

Comment: wanna know something? a got lost haha lol, ok i'll check maybe i figured how to make that, otherwise, can i still ask you if i don't understand ?

Comment: The thing is, that you have to tell the widget, that it should update it's content. Method widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler() is basically called only when the widget is displayed. Please check [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html) first. There is lot of tutorials, like [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83809/ios-8-today-extension-tutorial) or [code.tutsplus.com](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-creating-a-today-widget--cms-22379).